# How to cleanly disconnect from a namespace in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, azure, websocket, socket.io

I have been trying to disconnect from a namespace or even from the main socket connection itself but have been failing. Below is my code

Server Side:

```
 socket.on('userDisconnect', function () {        
    socket.disconnect();
    console.log("User Disconnected");       

});
```

Client Side:

```
// already connected to /world namespace
socket.emit('userDisconnect');
    socket.disconnect();
socket = io.connect('http://something/india' );
```

I tried disconnecting from both client and serve side but it doesnt work. Can anyone point out the mistake.
This is what is been written to console by socket.io

```
   info  - booting client
 debug - websocket writing 0::/world
User Disconnected
   debug - client authorized for /india
   debug - websocket writing 1::/india
```

/world is the namespace its trying to disconnect from and then its trying to connect to /india namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
broadcastSocket.packet({ type: 'disconnect' });
    broadcastSocket.$emit('disconnect');
    disconnectNamespace(broadcastSocket.name, broadcastSocket.socket);        


function disconnectNamespace (name,socket) {
    if (socket.namespaces[name]) {
        var nsp = socket.of(name);
        nsp.packet({ type: 'disconnect' });
        nsp.$emit('disconnect');
        delete socket.namespaces[name];

        if (Object.keys(socket.namespaces).length === 0) {
            socket.disconnect();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For socket.io v.1.3.2

Create with:

```
sio = io('ws://localhost:13000/device');
```

Delete with:

```
sio.disconnect();
delete sio.io.nsps[sio.nsp]; // sio.nsp = '/device'
delete sio;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On the server

```
nsp.on('connection', (socket) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      socket.disconnect(false)
   }, 5000);
});
```

Disconnects this client. If the value of close is true, closes the underlying connection. Otherwise, it just disconnects the namespace. It's in the documentation https://socket.io/docs/server-api/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you told the client to wait for disconnect before reconnecting.

```
// already connected to /world namespace
socket.emit('userDisconnect');
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  socket = io.connect('http://something/india');
  // stuff with india socket
});
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. But even after following your suggestion, i am getting the same issue :(

Comment: Is there any way to check if the socket is disconnected or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use disconnect() method on the server or on the client (or both like your did in your example). When you first connect to the server, add 'forceNew':false to the client connect method, something like this:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3001', {'forceNew':false});
```